# Is there a replacement for the -P option in tar, when using the POSIX version of tar (not the GNU version)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, posix, tar

I had a script that used tar as follows : tar -cPz and this worked as I want it to

Now however, i'm moving away from bash to a POSIX compliant shell, which means the -P option is no longer supported by tar. I guess this is because i'm now using the POSIX version of tar and no longer the GNU version

So my question : how do i keep it working as it did with the -P option, so how do i prevent tar from removing the leading '/'.

I've read some stuff about 'this is usually not what you want' etc, but in my case, i would like to keep it as it is, so i'm wondering if there is a way to keep this functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Technically there is no POSIX version of `tar` - it uses a command named `pax` to work with tar files (Among other formats).

Comment: Anyways, just `cd /` before extracting?

Comment: @Shawn Given the archive created with `tar -cP -f archive.tar bar /path/to/foo`, `cd /` would extract `/path/to/foo` correctly, but `bar` would always be extracted as `/bar` when it should be extracted to the current working directory.

Comment: As Shawn stated, [pax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html) is what you're looking for, though its usage is a bit different from `tar`.  Of course, you'll encounter more trouble porting `tar -cPz ...` since the POSIX-compliant equivalent is `pax -w ... | gzip ...` and `gzip` isn't POSIX either (but `compress` is).  Unfortunately, not all POSIX utilities like `ed` and `pax` are available in all POSIX-like environments, or they may require installation via package manager first.